# Increase height of the JTextField component

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

I am creating a calculator using Java Swing. But I am not able to increase the height of the JTextField component. Please find the code below:

```
JTextField textField = new JTextField(100);
JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
mainPanel.add(textField, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
```

The text field appears very small. How do I increase the height of the textbox to make it more prominent ?

Thanks

Comment: *`new JTextField(100);`* Just checking, you realize the `100` is not pixels, right?

Comment: yes, its not pixels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think better is to let the text field determine the height based on the font used.

```
String str = "21564";
JTextField textField = new JTextField(str, 100);
Font bigFont = textField.getFont().deriveFont(Font.PLAIN, 150f);
textField.setFont(bigFont);
mainPanel.add(textField);
```

See the [Swing Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)

Comment: Hardcoding the size is not recommended. Also, yes, changing the font will be able to increase its size, but it is not exactly what OP asks for.

Comment: Font bigFont = textField.getFont().deriveFont(Font.PLAIN, 150f);
textField.setFont(bigFont);
Setting bigger font did increase the height of the textfield.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Thanks for explaning. I will edit my post.

Comment: (1+) Also, agree changing the Font will make the text field more prominent.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to achieve it. First, is to [use a proper Layout Manager.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) It is always recommended not to mess with a bunch of hardcoded values and let APIs to do what they supposed to do. However, without a [short self contained example](http://sscce.org/) is hard to guess what you know and use and what you don't.

So I guess another way is to create an empty border to the component (or its parent container accordingly). In `JTextField` though, you might want to keep the default border, so you will have to use a compound one:

```
JTextField field = new JTextField(20);
Border outsideBorder = field.getBorder();
Border insideBorder = BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 0, 10, 0); //insets
field.setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(outsideBorder, insideBorder));
frame.add(field);
```